# Is it possible to add a subdomain to Route53 using the AWS PHP SDK?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, aws-sdk

I am working on a project where we will be creating both subdomains as well as domains in Route53.  We are hoping that there is a way to do this programmatically.  The SDK for PHP documentation seems a little light, but it appears that createHostedZone can be used to create a domain or subdomain record and that changeResourceRecordSets can be used to create the DNS records necessary.  Does anyone have examples of how to actually accomplish this?

Comment: For Clarity in Route53 a Public Hosted Zone is a domain name.  Then under that HostedZone->RecordSets are the individual records (A, CNAME, MX, DNS) etc

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using the `changeResourceRecordSets` call, as you already indicated. But it is a bit clumsy since you have to structure it like a batch even if you're changing/creating only one record, and even creations are changes. Here is a full example, without a credentials method:

```
<?php

// Include the SDK using the Composer autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\Route53\Route53Client;
use Aws\Common\Credentials\Credentials;

$client = Route53Client::factory(array(
    'credentials' => $credentials
));

$result = $client->changeResourceRecordSets(array(
    // HostedZoneId is required
    'HostedZoneId' => 'Z2ABCD1234EFGH',
    // ChangeBatch is required
    'ChangeBatch' => array(
        'Comment' => 'string',
        // Changes is required
        'Changes' => array(
            array(
                // Action is required
                'Action' => 'CREATE',
                // ResourceRecordSet is required
                'ResourceRecordSet' => array(
                    // Name is required
                    'Name' => 'myserver.mydomain.com.',
                    // Type is required
                    'Type' => 'A',
                    'TTL' => 600,
                    'ResourceRecords' => array(
                        array(
                            // Value is required
                            'Value' => '12.34.56.78',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
));
```

The documentation of this method can be found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.Route53.Route53Client.html#_changeResourceRecordSets). You'll want to take very careful note of the required fields as well as the possible values for others. For instance, the `name` field must be a FQDN ending with a dot (.).

Also worth noting: You get no response back from the API after this call by default, i.e. there is no confirmation or transaction id. (Though it definitely gives errors back if something is wrong.) So that means that if you want your code to be bulletproof, you should write a Guzzle response handler AND you may want to wait a few seconds and then run a check that the new/changed record indeed exists.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello @Neal Do you have any idea how can we create a subdomain from the elastic beanstalk?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I done using `changeResourceRecordSets` method.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\Route53\Route53Client;
use Aws\Exception\CredentialsException;
use Aws\Route53\Exception\Route53Exception;

//To build connection
try {
    $client = Route53Client::factory(array(
        'region' => 'string', //eg . us-east-1
        'version' => 'date', // eg. latest or 2013-04-01
        'credentials' => [
                    'key' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', // eg. VSDFAJH6KXE7TXXXXXXXXXX
                    'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', //eg. XYZrnl/ejPEKyiME4dff45Pds54dfgr5XXXXXX
              ]
    ));
} catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
}

/* Create sub domain */

try {

    $dns = 'yourdomainname.com';
    $HostedZoneId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'; // eg. A4Z9SD7DRE84I ( like 13 digit )
    $name = 'test.yourdomainname.com.'; //eg. subdomain name you want to create 
    $ip = 'XX.XXXX.XX.XXX'; // aws domain Server ip address
    $ttl = 300;
    $recordType = 'CNAME';
    $ResourceRecordsValue = array('Value' => $ip);

    $client->changeResourceRecordSets([
        'ChangeBatch'  => [
            'Changes' => [
                [
                    'Action'            => 'CREATE',
                    "ResourceRecordSet" => [
                        'Name'            => $name,
                        'Type'            => $recordType,
                        'TTL'             => $ttl,
                        'ResourceRecords' => [
                            $ResourceRecordsValue
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'HostedZoneId' => $HostedZoneId
    ]);
}
```

If you get any error please check into server error.log file. If you get error from SDK library then there is might PHP version not supported.
if you run this code from your local machine then you might get "**SignatureDoesNotMatch**" error then Make sure run this code into same (AWS)server environment.

Comment: Nice code. This is working fine.

Comment: This like is for those who faced issue to get key and secret details https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-appendix-sign-up.html